# Выполнение методов при переключении меню Switch Item

Tags: android

В выдвигающееся меню слева добавила элемент `Switch Item`. Как сделать, так, чтобы при открытии активити, если переключатель выключен выполнялся метод `meth1()`, а если включить, то `meth2()`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_switch"
            android:title="Switch"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_item"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: у него есть метод onCheckedChanged, который принимает два параметра. один из них boolean isChecked соответственно if (isChecked) то один метод else другой

Comment: Это где прописать? тут? @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 int id = item.getItemId();

 if (id == R.id.app_bar_switch) {

 }

 DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
 return true;
}

Comment: Это же вообще не отсюдова

Comment: это я скопировала кусок кода, где действия с левым меню